# Can a QObject living in one thread emit a signal from another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety, qthread

I have an object `a` created in the main thread, where its signals are connected to slots of another object, `b`, that also lives in the main thread.

Then I create an object `c` and move it to a `worker` thread, where it will **periodically** access object `a` through a pointer, change its state and emit its signals.

Here is the code:

(**Note:** some lines were purposely ignored to keep the example short.)

```
class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    friend class C;
signals:
    void sigA();
private:
    quint8 _m1;
    quint8 _m2;
};

class B : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void slotB();
};

class C : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    C(A* a) : _a{a}, _timer{new QTimer{this}}
    {
        _timer->setInterval(5);
        connect(_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &C::doSomeWork);
    }

public slots:
    void start() { _timer->start(); }

private slots:
    void doSomeWork()
    {
        // update members of `a`
        emit _a->sigA();
        // ...
    }

private:
    A* _a;
    QTimer* _timer;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    A* a {new A};
    B* b {new B};
    QObject::connect(a, &A::sigA, b, &B::slotB);

    QThread* worker {new QThread};
    C* c {new C{a}};    
    c->moveToThread(worker);

    QObject::connect(worker, &QThread::started, c, &C::start);    
    worker->start();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I hope *`a` signals*, emitted from thread `worker`, will trigger *`b` slots* in the main thread. And I hope I'll have no concurrency problems because `a` members are 8-bit sized.

But `c`, that lives in thread `worker`, will be posting events in the main thread event queue. I am not using any synchronization primitive, so I'm afraid I may run into problems.

Is it OK to use the signal/slot mechanism the way I'm using it in the code example? Is there something I need to worry about?

Comment: As long as your signal-connection is a QueuedConnection, Qt's signal/slots mechanism will make sure that the slot gets called from within the slot-object's thread:  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum